# Android NDK: Module main depends on undefined modules: SDL2

Tags: android, module, sdl-2

I've been following this SDL2 tutorial from LazyFoo: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/android_windows/index.php

But when I try to run the `ndk-build` command, it gives me the following error:

```
Android NDK: Module main depends on undefined modules: SDL2
Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by using an older version of the android NDK. I used 13b. You can download it here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html